# Why value of my JSON variable has "type" and "data" instead?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

For some reason, after doing a JSON.stringify() to my object into a file, one of my parameter does not have the string value assigned, but instead it has a "type" and "data".

Code:

```
fs.writeFileSync('myjson.json', JSON.stringify(myjsonobj, null, 4));
```

Expected:

```
{
  "my-field": "D21"
}
```

What I got instead:

```
{
  "my-field": {
    "type": "Buffer",
    "data": [
      68,
      50
      49
    ]
  }
}
```

The value under "data" seems to be the decimal value of each of the character of the string.

So, why am I having that of data?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because whatever value you are setting `my-field` to is a `Buffer`, and not a string. It's easy to correct; all you need to do is call `.toString()` on the Buffer when setting `my-field`. Like this:

```js
const myData = {
    'my-field': MyBufferVariable.toString()
};

return JSON.stringify(myData);
```

Comment: That was easy! Thanks so much!